# Implementing Markerless Augmented Reality in Android

Tags: android, augmented-reality, gyroscope

I'm trying to implement a simple augmented reality tool for Android.  All it needs to do is take as input my location and device orientation and the location of another device and present a camera view with an icon overlaid in the appropriate place in an appropriate size.

I'm stuck in two places:

I wrote code to get updates for the current azimuth, pitch, and roll of the device.  The code looks like this:

```
    private final SensorEventListener goodListener = new SensorEventListener() {
    private float[] magneticValues;
    private float[] accelerometerValues;

    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
    }

    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        switch (event.sensor.getType()) {
        case Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD:
            magneticValues = event.values.clone();
            break;
        case Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER:
            accelerometerValues = event.values.clone();
            break;
        }

        if (magneticValues != null && accelerometerValues != null) {
            float[] outR = new float[9];
            float[] orientationValues = new float[3];

            SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(outR, null,
                    accelerometerValues, magneticValues);
            SensorManager.getOrientation(outR, orientationValues);

            double azimuth = Math.toDegrees(orientationValues[0]);
            double pitch = Math.toDegrees(orientationValues[1]);
            double roll = Math.toDegrees(orientationValues[2]);

        }
    }
```

When I use logging to read these values, they seem relatively stable, but they do not seem to correspond to angles around any natural set of axes, and I can't figure out what the numbers represent.  How should I interpret these numbers?

The tutorial at http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/42482/0/page/3 takes a much simpler approach, but I cannot get it to work.

Once I have my device's azimuth, pitch, and roll, along with my latitude and longitude and that of the other device, how can I determine where to put the icon on the screen?  This seems to be a complicated geometry problem where we must imagine the view field of the camera as an infinite cone, project it onto the surface of the earth, and see if the other location is inside the projected area, but this seems awfully complicated.  Is there a better way that I'm overlooking?

Answer (score 1):

It's not a direct answer to your question, but you can try to take a look at [mixare](http://www.mixare.org) [source code](https://github.com/mixare/mixare).

The core code that may be of interest for you is in this class:
https://github.com/mixare/mixare/blob/master/src/org/mixare/MixView.java
around line #212 and onwards.

As you can see the code does not use azimut, pitch and roll but rather is manipulating the matrices.

As for the geometry problem, I do not understand when you say "project [the FOV of the camera] onto the surface of the earth". I'd have said that the FOV is projected onto a virtual sphere that surrounds the user.